# stdin is not a tty when try to run multiple commands using '&' operator in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I was working with a microservice project, so I needed to run all services at once so I set up bash script but throw ***stdin is not a tty*** error and run only the last line of command

```
yarn --cwd /d/offic_work/server/customer/  start:dev  &
yarn --cwd /d/offic_work/server/admin start:dev       &
yarn --cwd /d/offic_work/server/orders/ start:dev     &
yarn --cwd /d/offic_work/server/product start:dev
```

[image]

Comment: Please don't post an image of your output, and edit it in your question as text

Comment: Could you tell me why ?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not particularly familiar with yarn, but "is not a tty" means it is seeking input from the user, and can't get any because you ran it in the background. So what you need to do is run it in the foreground, find out what input it is seeking, then figure out what command line arguments, or otherwise configuration will let it run without user intervention. Then when you know that you can alter your script or take appropriate action so that it can run in the background.

In some cases, programs expect a user confirmation "y" to some question. That's why in unix the "yes" command exists, which outputs endless "y"s for such a purpose. You could also try piping yes to your command:

```
yes | yarn --cwd /d/offic_work/server/customer/  start:dev  &
```

Answer (score -1):

#### first

Create a list of your services i.e. `list.txt`

```bash
customer
admin
orders
product
```

#### second

Run them in parallel with `xargs -P 0`

```bash
# dry-run - test
xargs -I SERVICE -P 0 echo "yarn --cwd /d/offic_work/server/SERVICE start:dev" < list.txt

# run - remove the echo
xargs -I SERVICE -P 0 yarn --cwd /d/offic_work/server/SERVICE start:dev < list.txt
```